# Vlookup function on a column SQL

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create v lookup function on a column
that is based on another column in the same table, basically I already did.

```
Create table Expense (
 card Int(12),
 Foreign Key (Card) References Money(Card),
 Amt_Used int(255)
)

Create table Money (
 Card int(12) Primary Key, 
 Original_Amt int(255), 
 Tot_Expense int(255)
)
```

In the **Tot_expenses** from the second table, I tried:

```
select sum amt used
from Expense
set inner join money on expense.card=money.card
```

... but it didn't work. What I want to do is create a sum from a credit card, considering there are more than one credit card.

Comment: first of all, ```sum``` is a function so try: ```SELECT SUM(amt_used) FROM ....``` and remove the "set" there ... but if you have "card" as PK in both table .... create one table instead

Comment: Thank you for the help, but what i want to try to solve is finding out if i can set a column in which there are total expense and the amount left on each credit card assuming the data that is generated on the expense are random do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Never save "total" in databases ... unless you doing data-mart of course. I recommend to read this: http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html